# JS object undefined problem

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var X = {
   a: [{name:john, phone:777},{name:john, phone:777},{name:john, phone:777}],
   b: [{name:john, phone:777},{name:john, phone:777},{name:john, phone:777}],
   c: [{name:john, phone:777},{name:john, phone:777},{name:john, phone:777}],
   d: [{name:john, phone:777},{name:john, phone:777},{name:john, phone:777}]


}

var str = JSON.stringify(X);
alert(str);


</script>
```

What's wrong with this object?? It alerts "Uncaught ReferenceError: john is not defined"
How come??

Comment: john needs to be in quotes as it is a string not a variable identifier

Comment: @meouw You should have made that an answer instead of a comment+1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need quotes around john. Otherwise it is referring to an variable/object that has not been created:

```
var X = {
  a: [{name:"john", phone:777},{name:"john", phone:777},{name:"john", phone:777}]
...
```

Your code would be valid if `john` was previously defined:

```
var john = "john";
var X = {
  a: [{name:john, phone:777},{name:john, phone:777},{name:john, phone:777}]
  ...
```

Now `john` is a variable representing the string "john", and the JSON is valid.

Answer (score 5):

Try `name: 'john'`, you want it to be a string.

If you simply write `john`, it will be interpreted as a lookup for a variable (including possibly a function) named `john`. Since it finds no variable with that name, it will say it is not defined.

Same will go with `phone`, if the value can be something like `123-456-78` (would be interpreted as 123 minus 456 minus 78). If there can be only numbers, your solution is fine as it is now, otherwise use `'123-456-78'`.

Answer (score 0):

Change X like below. The object attribute names should be single or double quoted. String value should be quoted as well.

```
var X = {
   a: [{"name":"john", "phone":777},{"name":"john", "phone":777},{"name":"john", "phone":777}],
...
};
```

Comment: `Object properties can be both notated as plain characters and as strings.` - from [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.general). So `name: 'john'` is perfectly right.